# Click para mostrar slide con jQuery

Tags: jquery

Quiero que, al tocar un botón, aparezca el menú y que al volverlo a tocar, desaparezca.
No entiendo por qué no funciona. Teóricamente está todo bien, ¿Alguien sabe alguna solución?

El código en cuestión es el siguiente, muchas gracias, pongo un poco más de texto porque la página no me deja publicar la pregunta, disculpen las molestias:

```js
$(document).ready(main);

document.getElementByClassName(".menu_bar").addEventListener('click', slide);

function main()
{
  //Para que al tocar el ||| aparezca y desaparezca el menu
  function slide()
  {
    document.getElementByClassName(".nav").toggle();
  }
  //Para que al tocar "Quienes somos?" E "Institutos Dependientes" aparezca o desaparezca
  $(".arriba").click(function(){
        $(this).children("ul").slideToggle();
    })
};
```

```html
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalabre=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="menu_bar">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/menu.png">Menu</a>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="arriba"><a href="inicio.php">Inicio</a></li>
          <li class="arriba"><a href="#">¿Quienes Somos?</a>
            <ul style="display: none;">
              <li><a href="quienessomos/historia.php">Historia</a></li>
              <li><a href="quienessomos/heraldica.php">Heráldica del logo</a></li>
              <li><a href="quienessomos/institucional.php">Institucional</a></li>
              <li><a href="quienessomos/autoridades.php">Autoridades</a></li>
              <li><a href="quienessomos/organigrama.php">Organigrama</a></li>
            </ul></li>
          <li class="arriba"><a href="galeria.php">Galería Digital</a></li>
          <li class="arriba"><a href="novedades.php">Novedades</a></li>
          <li class="arriba"><a href="contacto.php">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
    <script>AOS.init();</script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="include/menu.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Un funcionamiento similar al botón de menú de Bootstrap?

Comment: Supongo que el problema es que quieres mostrar elementos "simples" usando funciones para sliders. Tal vez sería suficiente cambiar `.slideToggle()` por [.toggle()](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: @Triby Tampoco funciona, no se que será, es mas, si pongo este código:
`$(".menu_bar").click(function()
{
  $(".nav").slideToggle();
});`
Si funciona, no se xq no puedo hacerlo de la otra forma, y me pidieron q lo haga de la otra forma no se xq jajajajajja

Comment: @padaleiana Claro, similar a un botón de menú de Boostrap

Comment: Puedes agregar un [repro] como snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`) para ejecutar el código en la pregunta misma.

Comment: El código esta muy bien. Y aunque hay una mezcla de Javascript puro con jQuery, funciona bien (si se agrega la librería de jQuery). No le encuentro problemas

Comment: @NarcisoAifuz Creo que es ese el problema, como le agrego la librería de jQuery?? Sinceramente se C++ pero no JavaScript, estoy haciendo todo al aire jajajajjaja, creo q me falta la librería esa, de donde la puedo sacar?

Comment: El principal problema es que estás mezclando jQuery con Javascript puro y, revisando la consola, tienes un error porque no existe el método `getElementByClassName()`, debe ser `getElementsByClassName()` (faltó una `s`) y, además, eso devuelve una colección en vez de un solo elemento, por lo que deberías recorrer en un ciclo para asignar evento.

Answer (score 1):

Puede que no necesites jQuery, hay muchas cosas que pueden hacerse con un poco de CSS y Javascript puro.

**Nota:** En lugar de usar `getElementsByClassName()` o similares, prefiero [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) para obtener un solo elemento y [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) para una lista de nodos, solo se debe proporcionar el selector CSS adecuado (por ID, clase, etiqueta, etc.)

Revisa los comentarios en el código para saber lo que se hace en cada paso.

```js
// Ejecutar hasta que se haya cargado el DOM
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
    // Asignar evento a enlace del menú
    document.querySelector('.menu_bar a').addEventListener('click', e => {
        // Alternar para agregar o quitar clase
        document.querySelector('.nav').classList.toggle('open');
    });
    // Obtener todos los submenús y recorrer para asignar evento
    document.querySelectorAll('.submenu > a').forEach(submenu => {
        // Evento para seleccionar elementos que muestran submenú
        submenu.addEventListener('click', e => {
            // e.currentTarget es el enlace que recibió clic
            // closest('li') es para acceder al contenedor común del enlace y submenú
            // querySelector('ul') selecciona el submenú
            // Alternar para agregar o quitar clase
            e.currentTarget.closest('li').querySelector('ul').classList.toggle('open');
        });
    });
});
```

```css
/* Ocultar menú moviéndolo a la izquierda */
.nav {
    margin-left: -100%;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
/* Mostrar el menu */
.nav.open {
    margin-left: 0;
}
/* Ocultar submenús asignando altura máxima en cero */
.nav ul {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
/* Mostrar submenús cambiando la altura máxima a un valor que permita mostrarlo */
.nav ul.open {
    max-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu_bar">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/menu.png">Menu</a>
</div>
<nav>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="arriba"><a href="inicio.php">Inicio</a></li>
        <li class="arriba submenu"><a href="#">¿Quienes Somos?</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="quienessomos/historia.php">Historia</a></li>
                <li><a href="quienessomos/heraldica.php">Heráldica del logo</a></li>
                <li><a href="quienessomos/institucional.php">Institucional</a></li>
                <li><a href="quienessomos/autoridades.php">Autoridades</a></li>
                <li><a href="quienessomos/organigrama.php">Organigrama</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="arriba submenu"><a href="#">Otro submenú</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="seccion/pagina1.php">Página 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="seccion/pagina2.php">Página 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Opté por utilizar `$(".menu_bar").click(function()
  {
    $(".nav").slideToggle();
  });` Ahora tengo otra consulta, como puedo hacer un IF con el width de la pantalla en ese momento? Porque cuando achico la pantalla no funciona, tengo que tocar F5 para que funcione (Iniciar la página con el width de celular)

Answer (score 0):

Realice un ejemplo de cómo usar la librería jQuery en este proyecto.

Se puede [descargar el archivo jQuery](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js) de su [sitio web](https://jquery.com/download/) y usar sin problemas en la computadora.

Pero también se puede mediante el CDN, usar el solamente el enlace de esa librería, como en este ejemplo, puesto la etiqueta al pie del body.

Modifique bastante el código para usar solamente con jQuery. Pero de igual forma, con tu código original funcionaria, siempre y cuando agregues en al final del body el script de jQuery.

```js
(function() {

let menu = $(".menu_bar");
let nav = $(".nav");
let arriba = $(".arriba");

$(menu).on("click", function() { slide() });    

function slide() {
    
    nav.slideToggle();

};

$(arriba).on("click", function() {
    
    $(this).children("ul").slideToggle();

});

})(jQuery)
```

```html
<html>
<body>        
    
    <div class="menu_bar"> 
        <a href="#"><img src="img/menu.png">Menu</a>
    </div> 
    
    <nav> 
        <ul class="nav"> 
            
            <li class="arriba">
                
                <a href="inicio.php">Inicio</a>
                
            </li> 
            <li class="arriba">
                
                <a href="#">¿Quienes Somos?</a> 
                
                <ul style="display: none;"> 
                    
                    <li>
                        
                        <a href="quienessomos/historia.php">Historia</a>
                        
                    </li> 
                    <li>
                        
                        <a href="quienessomos/heraldica.php">Heráldica del logo</a>
                        
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        
                        <a href="quienessomos/institucional.php">Institucional</a>
                        
                    </li> 
                    <li>
                        
                        <a href="quienessomos/autoridades.php">Autoridades</a>
                        
                    </li> 
                    <li>
                        
                        <a href="quienessomos/organigrama.php">Organigrama</a>
                        
                    </li> 
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav> 
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ahi me di cuenta q si habia añadido la librería (Solo q la latest) La cambié x la q me pusiste y tampoco funcionó, no se que onda, ahora voy a intentar modificar la pregunta para que se pueda ejecutar el código, si lo puedo ejecutar entonces no se que será